# Why is my AWS Lambda Function returning null? (Python code)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a REST API to update my DynamoDB table whenever my web page is refreshed. I want to print the value that has been updated to show on my web page.

I initially had one Python function in my Lambda function. I added a second function to get an item from the DynamoDB table when I saw null when I would test the function. The logs still show null after adding the second function.

The DynamoDB table updates whenever the page is refreshed. The API test logs show a status of 200.

Below I will post my code and the API test logs.

```
    import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context, callback):
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName='ResumeCounter',
        Key={
            'Site': {
                'N': '0'
            }
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET Visits = Visits + :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': {'N': '1'}
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

def lambda_get(event, context):
    res = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='ResumeCounter',
        Key={
            'Site': {
                'N': '0'
            }
        },
        ProjectionExpression='Visits',
    )
    print(res)
```

```
Thu Jun 18 01:55:44 UTC 2020 : Method response body after transformations: null
Thu Jun 18 01:55:44 UTC 2020 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=[REDACTED];Sampled=0, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json}
Thu Jun 18 01:55:44 UTC 2020 : Successfully completed execution
Thu Jun 18 01:55:44 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Comment: Where do you return anything other than Null? Also, it seem a little strange that your python handler is taking a callback. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html for a typical python lambda function handler.

Comment: Your `lambda_handler` function doesn't return anything, which results in it returning `None`.  You're assigning a value to `response`, then discarding it and returning `None`.

Comment: And `lambda_get` is also returning `None`, after printing `res`.  You probably want to return `res` rather than printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print command merely prints this out to the console/logs. It does not return the values to the calling service (e.g. API gateway).

To return something to API Gateway, return the response using `return response` or `return json.dumps(response)`. That way the calling application will see a response, instead of getting a null response.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This really helped, keithRozario.

Now, I have updated my code to include a return call. It prints more information than I want, though. I would like it to only post the number of visitors to the site. Instead it posts "{"N": "103"}" Do you know how I would get it to only show 103? I have tried a get.item function but it did not work for me

Comment: Depending on the calling service, IIRC, you have to return a valid JSON object, and 103 is not a valid JSON. You need to extract it using your calling application. In python use the response.get(“N”) in your example.

Comment: Thank you! It is now returning the number, but it has quotation marks around it. I'm looking at https://realpython.com/python-json/ to try to find out how to fix it. You have been such a great help!!

Comment: Using "return int(count)" took away the quotations.

Comment: I didn't know you could return a pure integer -- but good to know :)